# Asynchronize vim script?

Tags: vim

I use vim to do some slowly operations after file saved, those operations let my vim got stuck, so I wondering is there some asynchronize method to make those operations run in background?

Demo:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.js call DoSomeTing()

function! DoSomeThing()
    " some operations really slow
endfunction
```

Comment: I don't think there's a generic async method.  However, if what you want involves launching an external process (such as ftp to upload that .js file for example) you can probably launch that in an async manner.

Comment: AFAIK Vim is single threaded. You can run (carefully) external background processes like `tags` generation but not Vim functions.

Comment: @Benj @romainl External process hardly to invoke some vim command like `:lcd`

Comment: @Ethan - Yes, that's why we gave you that caveat, it might be that you can't do what you want.  Although perhaps you should state in your question exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the more powerful language bindings (such as Python) to start a new thread and do your work in there. This is generally a really difficult task to get right, however. Also you really must not attempt to modify any vim structures or call any vim functions from these other threads - nothing in the vim core is thread safe.

Comment: Would this work?  I agree you could create a new thread easily enough in one of the supported languages, but vim will still wait until that python/perl/ruby process is finished before it returns.  So to get this to work you'd actually have to create a seperate process which runs in parallel with vim and services async requests.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by vim waiting for the process to finish - there would be no new process, I'm talking about creating a thread using a language embedded into vim, if vim is compiled with +python for example.

Comment: If vim is compiled with +python, that means that when a python script is embedded into a vim function, a python child process is launched when that function needs to run.  This child process will (I think) live for the lifetime of the vim function meaning that no matter how many threads you create in python the vim function still can't return.

Comment: Tom - Apologies, I've realised it doesn't work that way, vim dynamically links to dlls for python/perl/ruby rather than launching processes, so what you've said is probably correct. +1